# Can you spot enemies in Star Wars: Battlefront

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I've been looking at some gameplay of the new SW: Battlefront but I haven't seen any one use spotting. Does this simply not exist in this shooter? Or does it work in a non-conventional way (e.g. by a special trait your persona could have)?

I have read reviews that say that it's a nice atmospheric shooter but that tactical teamplay is missing (possibly deliberately so). I'm wondering if "tagging"/"spotting" is one of those missing features.

Comment: Not sure about the downvoters but it might be worth explaining what you mean by "spotting". I think you probably mean being able to ID an enemy such that others on your team can know where they are too but its not explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Star Card called Scan Pulse which gives you the ability to reveal all nearby enemies to you and your team.

Also, there's a droid power up that can attack and scan the area. The Imperials get the Viper Probe Droid, while the Rebels use the Astromech Droid

Comment: Wait, powerups are dependent on your team? Mind=blown I never noticed that.

Answer (score -1):

**No. This feature does not Exist.**

The only way to "see" people are by looking into their face, or any other body part(meaning seeing them on screen) or tracking them on your minimap. Sprinting and Fireing Weapons make them appear however there is the [Scout-Trait Card](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Scout) which depending on it's level will hide them.

Comment: Incorrect. Scan Pulse and the droid powerups will show ghost (outline) images of nearby enemies to everyone on your team.